# does file deleting and saving functions work fine in live environment(after host the site), mvc, c#

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I'm creating a web site using mvc,c#. Inside my web site I have written a method to delete and save file from the internet when button click.what I want to know , is this works fine in live environment.

this is how I delete and save.

```
 WebClient nileClient = new WebClient();
            string nileResult = nileClient.DownloadString(webserviceUrl);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            XmlDocument cruisexmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            //D:\PROJECT\TCUK_Web\TravelCenterSolution\Tour_CenterWeb\CruiseXmlFile\
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\WEB\Source\Workspaces\TCUK Web Projects\TravelCenterSolution\Tour_CenterWeb\XmlFiles\CruiseData\cruiseproducts.xml"))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\WEB\Source\Workspaces\TCUK Web Projects\TravelCenterSolution\Tour_CenterWeb\XmlFiles\CruiseData\cruiseproducts.xml");
                cruisexmlDocument.LoadXml(nileResult);
                cruisexmlDocument.Save(@"C:\Users\WEB\Source\Workspaces\TCUK Web Projects\TravelCenterSolution\Tour_CenterWeb\XmlFiles\CruiseData\cruiseproducts.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                cruisexmlDocument.LoadXml(nileResult);
                cruisexmlDocument.Save(@"C:\Users\WEB\Source\Workspaces\TCUK Web Projects\TravelCenterSolution\Tour_CenterWeb\XmlFiles\CruiseData\cruiseproducts.xml");
            }
```

Comment: That might not work if your Application Pool has no access to the C:\Users\, also address is hardcoded, and that`s not good.

Comment: @Bill, this actually depends upon the directory rights. Try with giving pull permission to application user over the mentioned directory. Put some logging to verify this.

Comment: so what I'm suppose to do.